# Multiple Choice Quiz in Python: how to assign number labels to dictionary random.sample output

Tags: python-3.x

Qlib is a dictionary of question:answer pairs like this:

```
Qlib = dict()
Qlib["Apple"]="green"
Qlib["Orange"]="orange"
Qlib["Banana"]="yellow"
Qlib["Strawberry"]="red"
```

Function for question shuffle:

```
def Qshuffle(self):
    for x in range(1):
        choices = random.sample(list(Qlib),4)
        random_fruit = random.choice(choices)
        main_typed = "Which fruit is the following colour...??\n\n\n"

        print('{0} {1}\n\n'.format(main_typed, random_fruit.center(85)))
        print('Choices:\n' + "\n".join([Qlib[x] for x in choices]))
    Options = ['Option [a]','Option [b]','Option [c]','Option [d]']
    for op in Options:
        print (op.rjust(38))
    answer = input("Enter answer a,b,c, or d")
```

Can someone point me in the direction of how to assign (a,b,c, or d) to the multiple choice options and to have the letters actually correspond with the random.sample choices? At the moment I can present the random question with the multiple choice answers but I don't know how to assign letters (a,b,c,d) or (1,2,3,4) to the multiple choices when they are created so that the user can just input 'a' or 'b' when selecting an answer and have that be assigned to a specific choice??

Comment: What do you mean "make it"? You can check whether the input is valid after it's in, but you can't force the user to only give valid input.

Comment: I mean if the user inputs say "a" for example, I don't know how to correspond the "a" or any of the letters to any of the actual answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store list of the choices and then get color based on the index of user's input. Then get the color from the dictionary and compare them.

Here is the working version:

```
import random

Qlib = dict()
Qlib["Apple"]="green"
Qlib["Orange"]="orange"
Qlib["Banana"]="yellow"
Qlib["Strawberry"]="red"

#defining options for further usage, optional but required in this code
letters = ["a","b","c","d"]

#I'm not sure about self in it
def Qshuffle(self):
    #I'm not sure this for x in range(1) is necessary
    for x in range(1):
        choices = random.sample(list(Qlib),4)
        random_fruit = random.choice(choices)
        main_typed = "Which fruit is the following colour...??\n\n\n"

        print('{0} {1}\n\n'.format(main_typed, random_fruit.center(85)))
        print('Choices:')
    #Defining/storing list of choices for further use, necessary
    options = list(Qlib[x] for x in choices)
    #some improvements of printing choices
    for i in range(len(options)):
        op = str(options[i])+" ["+str(letters[i])+"]"
        print(op.rjust(38))
    answer = input("Enter answer a,b,c, or d\n>>> ")

    if answer.lower() in letters:
        ########
        #Some debug information, can be deleted
        print("="*5)
        print(Qlib[random_fruit])                       #the color of random fruit
        print(letters.index(answer.lower()))            #index of selected answer
        print(options)                                  #list of options
        print(options[letters.index(answer.lower())])   #the color that user selected
        print("="*5)
        ########
        #checking that user chose the color of the random fruit
        if Qlib[random_fruit] == options[letters.index(answer.lower())]:
            print("correct")
        else:
            print("wrong")
    else:
        print("incorrect input")

Qshuffle("")
```

Comment: This works great! Thanks! Does exactly what I need! The "self" is because the function is part of a class. I'll test it without the "for x in range(1)" part also based on your suggestion thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You question is a bit difficult to understand but I guess you tried to check whether the user's answer is the same as the randomly picked value. If that's the case then this would do:

```
Qlib = dict()
Qlib["Apple"]="green"
Qlib["Plum"]="purple"
Qlib["Banana"]="yellow"
Qlib["Strawberry"]="red"

def qshuffle():
    choices = random.sample(list(Qlib),4)
    random_fruit = random.choice(choices)
    print("Which fruit is of {0} colour??\n".format(Qlib[random_fruit]))
    print('--- Choices: ---\n' + "\n".join([x for x in Qlib]))
    answer = input("You answer is >> ")

    if answer.capitalize() == random_fruit:
        print("That's right")
    else:
        print("Sorry, wrong answer.")
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but doesn't exactly achieve what I want. Firstly, your solution asks: "which fruit is of 'apple' colour??" and then the choices are ,green, purple etc., the next problem is that your solution requires the user to type in the name of the fruit/fruit colour in the answer field. The answer choices in my actual quiz are not fruit colours but several words (the name of a person and their organisation) so I don't want user to have to type the answer out fully but simply input a,b,c, or d (or 1,2,3, or 4) where the letters or numbers correspond to the random answers.